# reload page after response from facebook api post to feed?

Tags: facebook

Im trying to reload a page after the response from the facebook api.
With the code below I update my database with the $.get('.... and if I set window.location.reload(); after the $ get, then it doesnt run the $ get, so the database is not updated? Without the window.location.reload it runs the $ get and updates the database.

```
function(response){

        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured' +response.error);
        } else {


            $.get('updatefacebookpost.asp?gallerier_id=<%=gallerier_id%>&gallery_id='+gallery_id+'&facebookPhotoId=' + response.id);
            alert('Posten is uploaded!\nPost IDnr: ' + response.id );
            window.location.reload();


        }
```

So how can I reload the page that sends the facebook post, after it gets its response?
Any input appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(response){

    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured' +response.error);
    } else {
        var url = 'updatefacebookpost.asp?gallerier_id=<%=gallerier_id%>&gallery_id='+gallery_id+'&facebookPhotoId=' + response.id;
        $.get(url,function(data) {
            alert('Posten is uploaded!\nPost IDnr: ' + response.id );
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'SAVE_TO DATABASE_URL',
  success: function() { window.location.reload() }
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.
$.get is just short for $.ajax isnt it?
Yes it works, now it updates the database and then reloads, good.
But how can I show the alert before it reloads?

Comment: You can do it just like you wrote in your original question of course.  :)